# SharePoint 2013 REST API Query Throws an Error Every Time I Try to Set a Variable to a Returned Value

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint-2013

I'm working in SharePoint 2013 using REST API to retrieve information from a document library called "Test Data Request" (internal name `Test%20Data%20Request`).  I've created a basic REST API query to retrieve all items using the code below:

```
$(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/sites/regulatory3/testdashboard/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test Data Request')/items", 
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
    }).success(function (data) {  

      alert("Test 1!");

      $.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {

         var ID = value.ID;

      }

      alert("Test 2!");

    }); 

    failure(function (data) {

      alert("Failure");

    });
});
```

If I comment out the "each" code...

```
//$.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {  

  //var ID = value.ID;

//}
```

The two alert pop-up, if I don't only the first pops-up, the second doesn't because the "each" code throws an error.

I've tried different versions of the query code such as:

```
url: "/sites/regulatory3/testdashboard/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test%20Data%20Request')/items", 

url: "/sites/regulatory3/testdashboard/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test Data Request')/items",
```

One other point - I'm running this from a Web Part page with multiple Content Editor Web Parts and two separate CEWP's have REST API calls, each to a different list/library.

Nothing works - I'm stumped!  Anyone know the problem (please provide examples and guidance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the end of the each method:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function (key, value) {

     var ID = value.ID;

});
```

Need a paren and semi-colon